# How to use String.index and nested function call inside an if then else block

Tags: string, ocaml

I'am actually kinda new to oCaml and trying to learn.
I'am facing a big problem on one of my functions.
It's inside a simple function (below), inside it i'am trying to check the validity of an email adress by checking if it has a '@' then a '.' and text before and after each.
(I don't wanna use Regexp, i'am really sorry if you only know how to do that with regexp but i will not take into account regexp answers ^^').

Here is the code, thank you in advance :

```
let checkMail mail =
if String.contains mail '@' = false
then false
else
    let tmp = String.sub mail (String.index mail '@') ((string_length mail) - (String.index mail '@')) in;;
    if tmp.length < mail.length && String.contains tmp '.' = true
    then
        let last = String.sub tmp (String.index tmp '.') ((string_length tmp.length - 1) - (String.index tmp '.')) in;;
        if last.length < tmp.length && last.length > 1
        then true
        else false
    else false
```

;;

Also i receive this error in the ocaml prompt: `File "yolo.ml", line 8, characters 105-107:
Error: Syntax error`

That correspond to the second if call, when i'am trying to find the right sub-string size by calling String.index at the end. It occurs on the `'@'`.

If you have any idea why, please be free to share it :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indeed, there is kind of a lot of wrong Ocaml syntax ;)

```
let checkMail mail =
if String.contains mail '@' = false
then false
else
    let tmp = String.sub mail (String.index mail '@') ((String.length mail) - (String.index mail '@')) in
if String.length tmp < String.length mail && String.contains tmp '.' = true
    then
        let last = String.sub tmp (String.index tmp '.') ((String.length tmp - 1) - (String.index tmp '.')) in
 if String.length last < String.length tmp  && String.length last > 1
        then true
        else false
    else false;;
```

Notably :

- last.length is not an Ocaml syntax, unless last is a record.
- Same for string_length : String.length.
- and ;; which appears just after in keyword at 2 locations

Comment: Yup, if you take a look at it i've changed the length.something by string_length in the first call to if :'D i've forgot to do that for the other, btw i see that you changed a lot of things in terms of syntax, that will be really helpfull for me to take a closer look at it, thank you so much !

Comment: Yeah, it compiles now :'D !

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see is this line:

```
let tmp = String.sub mail (String.index mail '@')
    ((string_length mail) - (String.index mail '@')) in;;
```

The `;;` is a signal to the toplevel (OCaml REPL) that you're done typing and that it should evaluate what you've typed so far. In this code since you haven't typed a full expression yet, it will cause a syntax error.

IMHO it's really helpful to think of `;;` as something you type only when talking to the toplevel. It's not part of the OCaml language per se (despite rumors to the contrary that I see all the time).

Comment: Yep, trying to change things on my side and i was thinking about that, thanks you a lot !